# Grant Windows Easy Transfer permissions without Domain Administrator access

Tags: windows, active-directory

Currently we require Domain Administrator access to transfer a domain account between computers using Windows Easy Transfer.
Is it possible to grant a user access to the Transfer without granting them full Domain rights?

Thanks.